# Match Up XmlNode entry to String text value

Tags: c#, xml, string, file

How do I search a xmldata file node for the exact text that I have in my string value.

I.e.: `string fullname = "John Smith"`
Search XmlData.xml for node "FullName" where the value of the text = "John Smith".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an xpath expression that goes something like this:

```
//FullName[.='John Smith']
```

It means find any element that has the name `FullName` and the value "John Smith".

For a sample on how to load up the document and use an xpath query, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx.aspx).  To test some xpath queries on a sample document, try [here](http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx?mid=82).